# How do I push my footnotes to the bottom of the page again?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Some time ago, I created a document with one of the two style templates we use in our company.

It has two sub-chapters in the same page, say 1.5 and 1.6, and both sub-chapters have some footnotes. The footnotes are displayed together, at the end of the page.

Now, I need to edit the document in order to use the other layout. I imported the master pages and the text styles from a different document, and the footnotes are now at the foot of each sub-chapter (my page has sub-chapter 1.5, its notes, then sub-chapter 1.6, then its notes).

Despite removing text in order to see if this was somehow caused by the different fonts, different margins (single column everywhere, in case you were wondering), different spacing that might have forced one note out of the page, nothing changes.

Copying all the text in a document that already uses the intended style results in the same problem.

What could this be? How can I get my notes to stick to the bottom of the page as they did before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept scouring the Internet for a solution and I finally found one.

My sub-chapter titles in the second style were spanning across all columns, despite there being just one column, and the notes were put right before the next column-spanning text.

Changing the column span of that paragraph style to "none" solved the problem.